# mobiscroll - selecting option on click

Tags: jquery-plugins, mobiscroll

I'm in the process of deciding how to implement "selects" on a site, and am strongly considering mobiscroll, there's just one little thing that's annoying me, and that's the "extra click" (compared to an old-fashioned dropdown) of the "set" button that's required after choosing an option.

My question is, is there a way to close the scroller and set the value when an option is chosen via click or touch, but not if a new option is "chosen" because of dragging the scroller or using the mousewheel?

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#myScroller').mobiscroll({
            preset: 'select',
            theme: 'android-ics',
            mode: 'mixed',
            display: 'bubble',
            rows: 7,
            inputClass: 'subtleDropdown',
            onChange: function(val, inst) {
                //I would think this is where it's supposed to go, no luck thus far though!
                console.log(this);
            },
        });

</script>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we decided not to use mobiScroll (too little info on it available), so I'm closing this question.